# Can the new messagebox be somewhere else?

Tags: support, design, popups

Apparently we have a new messagebox:

[image: messagebox]

#### Can it please be screen-centered or near the action I took?

It is on the top but I clicked to delete a comment on the bottom. The mouse movings give me muscle ache.

Comment: It's just a `confirm()` box, the browser decides the positioning.

Comment: It is Chrome 29.0.1547.57m on Win7 64bit.

Comment: Ugh, ugh, ugh, ugh. This is something the new version of Chrome introduces, I'll bet, and it's awful. Continuing their theme of sub-par reinventions of native UI elements... I haven't updated yet, but I will be angry when I do restart tomorrow.

Comment: Apparently [it could be worse...](https://chromium.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=2771210000000&name=ConfirmRemoval.png&token=Xt6qvY_SHhvS1uIoKGX_X7RJypI%3A1377257927403&inline=1).

Comment: You have to take this up with the Chrome people, not us. (For what it's worth, I agree with you.)

Comment: @CodyGray: The really goddamned annoying thing about it is that it is just a styled modal window.  It looks like it should be blocking to the webpage that spawned it, but it in fact is a modal dialog that blocks all chrome windows.

Comment: *And* you can't even suppress them anymore! :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have updated to the new chrome.

This is a regular confirm box, in the new chrome update (Version `29.0.1547.57 m` on my machine) they have changed the look and position of the confirm.

Comment: ***My cheese!!!*** Those profoundly ***insensitive clods*** have no souls.

Comment: Man, I have got to start keeping my cheese under lock and key... Hey you kids, get off my lawn!

Comment: @CodyGray I know, right?! Solution is simple, everyone should write their own web browser from scratch.

Comment: Nah, don't be ridiculous. :-) We don't have to write anything from scratch, the Chromium project is already open-source. They got *most* everything right as far as I'm concerned. But I am actually thinking of forking and fixing the handful of things the developers are breaking and digging their feet in about fixing. I mean, isn't that what programmers do? I just need to come up with a better name than Non-Broken-Chrome, or Chrome-With-Native-UI-Elements. @grant

Comment: @CodyGray NBCWNUIE? That's another thing [at least] some programmers do. Seriously, though, that's a very reasonable idea, provided you have the time! In total, you might well make all the time back in productivity within the browser from not having to hunt for nuisances like this in order to continue.